# Compile error with thrust::device_vector of thrust::complex, possibly due to a wrong implementation

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm actually learning **CUDA** and **thrust**, and I'm trying to make a project with `.cpp`, `.hpp` files and `.cu`, `.cuh` files. Therefore, I have done a first little implementation (see code below), however I have a compile error. Here is the [output](https://pastebin.com/RdNhGPyi) of my compile error.

Honestly, I don't know exactly what this kind of error means, but I found out that this came from this line:

```cpp
thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<T>> deviceVec_;
```

because when I comment out this line there is no compile error anymore. Therefore, I assume that this is due to the content of the implementation of `thrust::device_vector` and the fact that I included the `.cuh` file in the `.hpp` file and since my `main.cpp` is handled by `g++` the preprocessing will be performed by `g++` instead of `nvcc`.

#### Content of my `main.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include "QGPU.hpp"
int main()
{
     QGPU::GPU<double>  gpu;
     return (0);
}
```

#### Content of my `.hpp` file:

```cpp
#pragma once

# include "QCUDA.cuh"

namespace QGPU {

 template<typename T>
 class GPU {
 private:
  QCUDA::CUDAGPU<T> cgpu_;
 public:
  GPU();
  virtual ~GPU();

};

template<typename T>
GPU<T>::GPU()
{};

template<typename T>
GPU<T>::~GPU()
{};

};
```

#### Content of my `.cuh` file:

```cpp
#pragma once

# include <thrust/host_vector.h>
# include <thrust/device_vector.h>
# include <thrust/complex.h>

namespace QCUDA {

 template<typename T>
 class CUDAGPU {
 private:
  thrust::host_vector<thrust::complex<T>> hostVec_;
  thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<T>> deviceVec_;
 public:
  CUDAGPU();
  virtual ~CUDAGPU();
 };

 template<typename T>
 CUDAGPU<T>::CUDAGPU()
 {};

 template<typename T>
 CUDAGPU<T>::~CUDAGPU()
 {};

};
```

Thus, my question is:

Is there a way to solve this compile error, and therefore, maintaining this implementation ?

Or I must change my vision on how I should implement a project where `.cpp`, `.hpp` files and `.cu`, `.cuh` files are mixed together ?

If I must change my implementation, there is a possibility to get a similar example of what would be a good implementation by following my attention ?

**NB:** I'm actually working with a GTX 1060 with the cuda version:

```
$nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Apr_11_23:16:29_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename `main.cpp` to `main.cu` to make this work. Otherwise you are importing CUDA code into a plain `.cpp` file, and the host C++ will fail to compile the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response @talonmies ! And by the way it compiles successfully. Howerver, I have made an assumption on what you said.

If I understand what you said, whenever I include a `.cuh` or perform an implementation where a CUDA part is expected I have to rename the file to a `.cu` in order to ensure that nvcc will process this file ?

Comment: That is correct. nvcc uses the file extension to determine how the code should be compiled